# Spring Security passepartout password

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've a client/server app using Spring and more specifically Spring Security to manage authentication of clients.
All works fine and this is the relevant part of the configuration:

```
<security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="
          select username,password,attivo 
          from Operatore where username=?"

            authorities-by-username-query="
          select username,ruolo 
          from Operatore where username=? " />

    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

My question if there is a way to authorize users that uses passepartout password. 
I mean, sometimes is confortable login in the software with a particular user using a super-admin password in order to see exaclty what the user see without change his password.

I think this behaviour is not contemplated from Spring; there is a way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own Authentication logic simply by wiring in your own implementation of an AuthenticationProvider and implementing the authenticate method as required:

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html

Further reading:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider

https://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/custom-authentication-provider-in-spring/

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-custom

Comment: I'd like to reuse the jdbc query as now (jdbc-user-service). In short my custom class should be as default one with a check before make the query on db.Which class I should check?